# Storyboard is not showing my components?

Tags: ios, storyboard

So I am in the middle of a app and then when I went to try to change something on the storyboard I noticed that all the components are now showing up on the board but they are good on the previews can someone tell me why?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your components are not enabled for your current size class.  That's why they are greyed out in the document outline.  Go to the Attributes inspector for your map view and scroll to the bottom:

[image: size class check boxes]

The check boxes at the bottom enable and disable the views in different size classes.  Make sure all of the check boxes are checked.

Comment: Ok I see, however, I had started out on the default size (Base Layout for all sizes) how did it universally change all my components to a different size class? Because I didn't start on the iPhone class size it just changed without me knowing? and do you know how I can change them all back at once. I mean I did do as you said but they came back all out of position, the constraints seem to be the only thing right now making sure my front end doesn't fall apart.

Comment: I don't know.  I haven't figured out when it decides to automatically add another checkbox.  You can add them manually by clicking the little + button (which is what I did to make that screen shot).

Comment: Thanks for your help HAHA I'll just do that. FREAK hahah